# AppleScript to copy PowerPoint slide from one presentation to another

Tags: copy, applescript, powerpoint, slide, presentation

I've got a PowerPoint file with a single slide and my goal is to copy that one slide into a different PowerPoint file.

*Using macOS Sonoma 14.0 with Microsoft Office 365 PowerPoint 16.78 (late 2023)*

I've tried several variations of:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate

    -- Get the source and destination presentations
    set sourcePresentation to open presentation file "source.pptx"
    set destinationPresentation to open presentation file "destination.pptx"

    -- Get the slide to copy from the source presentation
    set sourceSlide to slide 1 of sourcePresentation

    -- Copy the slide to the destination presentation
    copy object sourceSlide
    paste object to destinationPresentation

    -- Close the source presentation
    close presentation sourcePresentation
end tell
```

Ultimately I'd like to point the final script at a folder full of .pptx files and have it insert the slide into each of destination deck in the second position. But I'd settle for a basic slide copy across decks right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. Note that there is a switch in 'mode' from *presentation* to *window* in order to use the `paste object` command.

It seems that the paste object will deposit whatever had been copied to *after* the selection — in this case, after slide 1.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    
    -- source   
    copy object slide 1 of presentation "source.pptx"
    
    -- destination
    select slide 1 of presentation "destination.pptx"
    
    tell active window
        set view type to slide sorter view
        paste object its view
        -- paste object view of active window -- alternate phrasing for when outside of tell block
        set view type to normal view
    end tell
    select slide 2 of presentation "destination.pptx" -- optional
    
end tell
```

You should be able to find numerous answers here that demonstrate using a repeat loop to cycle through a list of files.

Specific to powerpoint though, the syntax for opening a file is just `open` followed by the file reference. You can get the file reference by using the `choose file` command. Try running something like `choose file` in a separate script and it will return the appropriate file reference. Then use that result with your open command in this script.